# social-auth-app-django error creating table for column social_auth_usersocialauth.created does not exist

Tags: django, oauth-2.0, facebook-authentication

I am not sure where is the issue and not sure why the auth package is not creating the table. but also the facebook individual verification is also disabled due to COVID-19. I don't get the option to verify which maybe why but I am not sure.

[the table error I get when I try to login through Facebook oauth2][1]
"""

```
#settings.py file settings
# pipeline
    SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = (
        'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.social_details',
        'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.social_uid',
        'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.social_user',
        'social_core.pipeline.user.get_username',
        'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.associate_by_email',
        'social_core.pipeline.user.create_user',
        'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.associate_user',
        'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.load_extra_data',
        'social_core.pipeline.user.user_details',
    )
    
    
    
    AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ['social_core.backends.facebook.FacebookOAuth2','django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',]
    
    SOCIAL_AUTH_URL_NAMESPACE = 'social'
    SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SCOPE = ['email']
    SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_KEY = '855857298498541' 
    SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SECRET = '9f5f0e8af7834122773d5b5f4ec03cb4' 
    SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SCOPE = ['email', 'user_link'] 
    SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_PROFILE_EXTRA_PARAMS = {       
      'fields': 'id, name, email, picture.type(large), link'
    }
    SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_EXTRA_DATA = [                 
        ('name', 'name'),
        ('email', 'email'),
        ('picture', 'picture'),
        ('link', 'profile_url'),
    ]
    SOCIAL_AUTH_REDIRECT_IS_HTTPS = True
    
# SOCIAL_AUTH_POSTGRES_JSONFIELD = True
    
# installed apps including all the packages
    INSTALLED_APPS = [
        'django.contrib.admin',
        'django.contrib.auth',
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
        'django.contrib.sessions',
        'django.contrib.messages',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles',
        'social_django',
        'django_extensions',
        'storages',
        'socialApp.apps.SocialappConfig',
    ]
    
    # middleware for the application
    MIDDLEWARE = [
        'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
        'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
        'social_django.middleware.SocialAuthExceptionMiddleware',
    ]
```

"""
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5Tnj.png